# Hyphen in physical quantities before nouns?

Tags: hyphenation, numbers, measuring-units

In cases where a physical quantity (consisting of a number and a unit) is used like an adjective to describe a property of an object, should it be written with or without a hyphen between the number and the unit?

Examples:

- "A 2 kilogram potato" or "A 2-kilogram potato"?
- "We use 4 Gbit memory devices" or "We use 4-Gbit memory devices"?

Is one of the forms correct, or are both forms possible?

The second example is supposed to refer to an unspecified number of memory devices with 4 Gbit (gigabits, of capacity) each, rather than four memory devices.

Does any of the following modifications make difference?

- The quantity is written as a word instead of digits, i. e. "A two kilogram potato" vs. "A two-kilogram potato" ("two" instead of "2")
- The unit is abbreviated rather than written out, i. e. "A 2 kg potato" vs. "A 2-kg potato" ("kg" instead of "kilogram")
- The quantity is a decimal fraction, i. e. "A 1.5 kg potato" vs. "A 1.5-kg potato"
- The quantity is a simple fraction, i. e. "A 1/2 kg potato" vs. "A 1/2-kg potato"?

Furthermore, would it ever be correct to use a hyphen in a case like "This potato has a weight of 2-kg" (or "2-kilograms")?

An answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related) (which discusses a different case) states that when there is no ambiguity, hyphens may be omitted. Does that statement apply to this case?

Note that this case is different from the case where [an ajdective is explicitly given](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69742/ways-to-write-2000-year-old) ([another example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8666/is-it-correct-to-write-a-5-mm-thick-layer)).

Comment: Closely related (and in the sidebar): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89931/usage-of-hyphens-with-numeric-measurements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule but, as always, you should use common sense and choose what you think makes reading your piece easier. I personally favour hyphenating any "number+unit" [complex modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier).

This practice is especially useful in scientific writing, as it mitigates ambiguity.

Moreover, it improves the reading flow, as hyphenated complex modifiers appear as blocks. Non-hyphenated complex modifiers, by contrast, tend to disrupt it; one often stumbles upon them, and then has to backtrack and read them again.

It's preferable to write:

> a 2-kilogram potato
>
> 4-Gb memory devices

Although this practice remains valid for "number+abbreviated unit" complex modifiers, it can lead to difficult parsing. In cases with simple units like *foot*, *meter* or even *light year*, the unabbreviated form may be preferable, as they are easy enough to parse. On the other hand, using the unabbreviated form of more complex units tends to make parsing difficult.

> a 5-meter-per-square-second acceleration

In those more complex cases, using the abbreviated form may be preferable.

Comment: What about "This potato has a weight of 2-kilograms"? This seems incorrect to me, but I've seen other people (also non-native-speakers, like myself) write things like that.

Comment: *This potato has a weight of 2-kilograms* is incorrect because "2 kilograms" is not used as a [complex modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) in that sentence. Therefore, it needs not be hyphenated. Another example: *I have an 8-year-old daughter*, and *My daughter is 8 years old*.