# 1.3 Liters or 1.3 Liter? Fractions and plural form

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

I searched Google, but I couldn't get exact result.

I think question is clear. Do you add 's' or not? 1.5 meter or meters , ...

Comment: 1.3 *litres* :)

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Cette question ne concerne pas la langue Française :)

Comment: @topomorto Obviously not—if it did, it would have been _**1,3** litres_. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet touché :) (I am in the UK anyway... we have litres too!)

Answer (score 3):

For straightforward expressions of volume, you would keep the 's':

> Here's 1.3 liters of beer.
>   The volume of this beer glass is 1.3 liters.
>   If I drink more than 1.3 liters of beer, I like to have some chips on the side.

For use as an adjective, omit the 's':

> Please give me *a 1.3 liter glass* of beer

here, you're using '1.3 liter' as an adjective in the same way that you might use 'large'. In this usage, some people would hyphenate to '1.3-liter': [Hyphen in physical quantities before nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/hyphen-in-physical-quantities-before-nouns).

It's similar with meters and most units - hence you would say that in a hundred-meter race, the athletes have to run one hundred meters. You would *say* it that way even if you were abbreviating to '100m' too.

Comment: As and adjective, is this true ---> Three 20 year old boys

Comment: 'Three 20 year old boys'  is correct, though you will often see hyphens in ages :  *20-year-old*. Some people might also put a hyphen in '1.3-liter' too : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/hyphen-in-physical-quantities-before-nouns

Comment: It's not just the same with metres and other measurements, but with (almost) _all_ nouns used attributively. It's also a _five-man army_, but an _army of five men_, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Before the noun: a 1.5 meter wall.
Otherwise: the wall is 1.5 meters long.